Convergence of sum of geometric random variables to a gamma distribution
Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ random variables i.i.d. with geometric distribution ($k \geq 1$) with parameter p. Define $Y_p := X_1 + \ldots + X_n$. Show that $p Y_p$ converges in distribution distribution for a Gamma distribution and show the parameters when $p \to 0$.
My first idea: I know that the momentum function of $X_1$ is
$$
M_{X_1}(t) = \frac{p}{1 - (1-p)e^t}
$$
then,
$$
M_{p Y_p}(t) = \left[ \frac{p}{1 - (1-p)e^{pt}} \right]^n
$$
and now I try to compare this with the momentum function of the $Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$
$$
M_{Gamma(\alpha, \beta)} = \left(\frac{\frac{1}{\beta}}{\frac{1}{\beta} - t}\right)^\alpha = \frac{1}{(1 - \beta t)^\alpha}
$$
Ok, that $\alpha = n$, but with the $\beta$ I don't see a match between these functions, maybe as a mistake.

The Gamma distribution takes two parameters: a shape parameter $k$, and a scale parameter $\theta$. For example, here, $Y_n:=X_1+\dots+X_n \sim \Gamma(n,p)$ (you can show this with your method, or Laplace transforms). In your question, is $p \to 0$, or $n\to +\infty$? If it is $p\to 0$, why doesn't the answer depend on $n$?

@Kolakoski54 $p \to 0$, if I understand the question, it depends, in fact, at the end I comment on having $\alpha = n$, but not identifying $\beta$.

See that
$$
  \left[ \frac{p}{1 - (1-p)e^{pt}} \right] 
$$ has $0/0$ form as $p\to 0$
So, apply L'Hospital's rule and see that the limit
$$\lim_{p\to 0}\left[ \frac{p}{1 - (1-p)e^{pt}} \right]=\lim_{p\to 0}\frac{1}{e^{pt}-(1-p)te^{pt}}=\frac{1}{1-t}$$
So $$M_{pY_{p}}(t)\xrightarrow{p\to 0} (\frac{1}{1-t})^{n} $$
which is the same as the moment generating function of a $\Gamma(n,1)$ distribution (for $t$ in proper range). Note that $n$ is fixed here.
This is enough to show the convergence in distribution.
Note:- The MGF of gamma distribution and Geometric distribution are not defined for all $t\in\Bbb{R}$. So it is always advisable to use Characteristic functions instead.
The same proof(almost the same) will show you that
$$\psi_{pY_{p}}(t)\xrightarrow{p\to 0} (\frac{1}{1-it})^{n}$$ which is the cf of a $\Gamma(n,1)$ distribution.
